# Can't figure out a way set the DOC file permission for single,multi or Enterprise user

Tags: django

I have been working on a Django project where a user is allowed to download the DOC file after he makes payment for the file.

But I can't figure out a way to restrict this doc file from being forwarded or copied. Please Help!!

Here is the Image if anyone can help.
[image]

Comment: License it and make it a violation of your terms to share? You are providing a file for download. You can’t control what the user does with that file. You can always password protect but that’s redundant.

Comment: $4250 for a .doc file wow

Comment: I answered anyway, but when I tried to change tags from Django (irrelevant - the issues are after the download is done and have **nothing** to do with the Django framework per se), I couldn't actually find a relevant tag - seems to not really be a programming question suitable for SO.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

There are different levels of protection that can be done. But in the end it really does come down to licensing (easy) and enforcement (hard). Opinionated comment: If you provide a product that is unique enough and high enough quality at a reasonable price, people will pay the fee and the "sharing" will be minimal. If the price is too high relative to the quality/value of the content then the "sharing" will be a big problem that you will be unable to enforce as a "little guy".

All that being said:

- DOC - assuming this means Microsoft Word compatible document

You can protect it with a password, but you have to give the user the password to use it. So that doesn't mean much except as an extra warning about the confidential (don't share) nature of the document. Once they get into it, they can mostly do whatever they want.

- PDF - With a PDF, you can have a password (same good/bad as with DOC). But the password can fairly reliably protect against copying or printing if you configure the password protection to limit copying or printing. But for most (not all) documents, if you prevent printing you prevent normal usage of the document, and if you allow printing then copying is trivial - even if it means printing and then scanning.

$4,250 is a lot of money. Provide quality content to customers that will truly spend the money and they will, hopefully, not share it simply because they don't want *their* competition to save $4,250 by getting it for free. But I struggle to figure out what DOC files would be worth that much.

Comment: Actually this is the site I followed.. It's.. I just wanted to check on how to implement the method.

Comment: As I noted in a comment on the question, I don't think this will be a Django issue but rather a DOC file format issue - i.e., is there any way to protect it sufficiently. Does it need to be **DOC** or is another format possible?

Comment: What file should one prefer for such protection??

Comment: Hard to say. Depends on the goal of the product.